# How to convert comma-separated key value pairs into a dictionary using lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

I'm having a little problem figuring out lamba functions. Could someone show me how to split the following string into a dictionary using lambda functions?

```
fname:John,lname:doe,mname:dunno,city:Florida
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is not really a need for a lambda here.

```
s = "fname:John,lname:doe,mname:dunno,city:Florida"
sd = dict(u.split(":") for u in s.split(","))
```

Comment: You beat me to it with exactly the same code.  :-)  Deleting mine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need lambda functions to do this:

```
>>> s = "fname:John,lname:doe,mname:dunno,city:Florida"
>>> dict(item.split(":") for item in s.split(","))
{'lname': 'doe', 'mname': 'dunno', 'fname': 'John', 'city': 'Florida'}
```

But you can if you really want to:

```
>>> dict(map(lambda x: x.split(":"), s.split(",")))
{'lname': 'doe', 'mname': 'dunno', 'fname': 'John', 'city': 'Florida'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you can even do this with two lambdas, but never try this at work! Just for fun:

```
s = "name:John,lname:doe,mname:dunno,city:Florida"
d = reduce(lambda d, kv: d.__setitem__(kv[0], kv[1]) or d, 
    map(lambda s: s.split(':'), s.split(',')),
    {})
```